# When is the right time to release properties?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have a couple of properties declared in my header file, and just wondering when they have to be released. I'm currently doing them in my "dealloc" method, but getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when doing so.

Here's my code

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *closeimage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *alertStyle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *phonelaunch;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *resultmessage;
```

Here's my dealloc method

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [timer release];
    [closeimage release];
    [alertStyle release];
    [phonelaunch release];
    [resultmessage release];
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put your `[super dealloc]` message at the **end** of your dealloc method.

Comment: does location of super affect everywhere?
i mean with viewDidLoad also...
[super viewDidLoad];

Comment: Think about what [super dealloc] does.  Now, try to imagine what kinds of issues might arise when you try to send messages to objects that are already deallocated.

Comment: +1 that is ok...with dealloc...but i want to know about affect of
position of
[super viewDidLoad];

or other super statements...